# Search for specific characters through an excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel

I've got an excel file and the table starts from the first row and the third column. In the first and third rows there are the alphabet letters.

What I want to do is to find a letter in the first row and then find another in the third column then find the int value that falls in their intersection (I'm using Apache POI).

I've used

```
cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)
```

to get me the reference but it kept returning the default value.

Thank you.

Comment: I've used cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent), to get me the reference but it kept returning the default value.

Comment: OK, so add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question showing exactly what you have tried, with any relevant context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that there was similar letters so the the code would find two cells and then return nothing. So in the excel file, I added a letter to the cells in the 3rd column and another letter to the 1st row in order to differentiate between them.

```
    for (Row row : sheet) 
    {
        for (Cell cell : row)
            {
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(targetLetter))
                        row1= row.getRowNum();  
                if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
                    if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(displayLetter)) 
                        col1= cell.getColumnIndex();  
                c= sheet.getRow(row1).getCell(col1); // c is of type Cell
            }
    }
```